# ce.Apparently the method is not static

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-view, android-context

I am new to java and android.The method `getContext()` is directly called without referenced by an instance of View class. Apparently the method is *not static*. How is it possible to call a non static method directly.What am i missing here ? Have added my code below (the doubt is in last line).
Thank you.

```
package in.shopperstreet.honeywell;


import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

public CustomAdapter(Context context, String[] books) {
    super(context,R.layout.activity_main2,books);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater lif = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
    ....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `getContext` method belongs to `ArrayAdapter`. from the documentation

> Returns the context associated with this array adapter. The context is used to create views from the resource passed to the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Use `getLayoutInflater()`, called on the activity hosting this adapter, over `LayoutInflater.from()`.

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    final private LayoutInflater li;

    public CustomAdapter(Activity host, String[] books) {
        super(host,R.layout.activity_main2,books);
        li=host.getLayoutInflater();
    }


    // other code goes here
}
```